# Браузер блокирует воспроизведение аудио при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, аудио, promise

Нужно сделать что бы при наведении на блоки воспроизводилось аудио дорожка, но именно при наведение брауйзер думает что это автовоспроизведение и блокирует.

Вот как я хочу запустить воспроизведение, при наведение на блоки, я нахожу аудио и включаю воспроизведение.

```js
$('.content__inner').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    var audio = $(this).find('audio');
    audio[0].play();
});

$('.main').on('mouseout', '.content__inner', function () {
    var audio = $(this).find('audio');
    audio[0].pause();
});
```

Как мне решить эту проблему?

[Ссылка](http://foto.shokoladagency.ru/product/musicview?id=092935621&search=)

Comment: Сейчас браузеры блокируют  звуковую рекламу, поэтому требуют от посетителя сайта активность - нажать кнопку, боюсь, что без клика не запустить.

Comment: Как это возможно сделать, вот тут это реализовано и работает при наведении.
https://www.pond5.com/ru/royalty-free-music/item/99532526-funk-and-funky

Answer (score 0):

Это можно решить с помощью динамического тега iframe:

```html
<div id=mydiv></div>
<button onmouseenter="start()" onmouseout="stop()"> наводим курсор на меня </button>
<script>
function start(){
    mydiv.innerHTML = "<iframe src='https://synthesizer.000webhostapp.com/synthesizer/sud.mp3' allow='autoplay' style='display: none'></iframe>";
}
function stop(){
    mydiv.innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Сейчас это уже тоже не работает. Событие onmouseover не считается таким, которое обеспечивает взаимодействие с посетителем, и потому будет включать воспроизведение только после другого взаимодействия. (клик, скролл, нажатие на любую клавишу.)